# HomeWork: Convert Feet to Inches with RNG

Tags: java, converters

"Write a program that will randomly generate a number of total inches. Then convert the total inches into feet and inches."

I need to make the output in this format:
14 inches is 1 feet, and 2 inches

I already have this starting code:

```
public class InchesToFeet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        convert(); // convert feet to inches and output
    }

    // This method generate a random number of total inches.
    // It then converts to feet and inches and outputs the answer.
    public static void convert() {

        // randomly picks a number between 1-200
        int totalInches = (int)(Math.random()*200 + 1);

        // Convert to feet and inches.
        // ex. if totalInches is 38, the output would be: 38 inches is 3 feet, and 2 inches
        // ADD CODE BELOW
    }
}
```

I read the chapter that our professor assigned but I am honestly lost on as to how to actually do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your aim, you need to first divide `totalInches` by your conversion factor (12) to see how many feet it contains, and then use the modulo operator (%) to get the number of inches - like so.

`System.out.println(totalInches + " inches is " + (int) (totalInches / 12) + " feet, and " + totalInches % 12 + " inches");`

Still, pasting homework on here isn't such a good idea.